# React Native - Update ListView by Picker

Tags: android, react-native

I try to fetch data from mySQL based on the 'Type' selected on Picker and update the ListView with the fetched data. So, I specify everything when the Picker's onValueChange will call the componentDidMount() function to fetch new data and update the ListView.

The problem is, when I select TypeA in Picker, the data in the ListView does not update, but when I select TypeB in Picker for the second time, the ListView updated based on TypeA. Then, I select TypeC, the ListView updated based on TypeB.

Is there is a problem with my code or I using the wrong method to do so?

```
export default class ProfileScreen extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    TypeInput : 'Vegetarian',
    isLoading: true,
  };

}

static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'View/Edit',
};


OpenSecondActivity(id) {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('Second', { ListViewClickItemHolder: id });
}

  componentDidMount() {

  return fetch('https://unsurfaced-cross.000webhostapp.com/getRecipeRN.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({

      RecipeType: this.state.TypeInput

    })

  }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((responseJson) => {

          // Fetch Data update the List View Content
          let ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson),

          });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }

  ListViewItemSeparator = () => {
         return (
           <View
             style={{
               height: .5,
               width: "100%",
               backgroundColor: "#000",
             }}
           />
         );
   }

render() {

const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

if (this.state.isLoading) {
          return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
              <ActivityIndicator />
            </View>
          );
        }


 return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={styles.text}>Recipe Type: </Text>

    <Picker
      style={{width: 200}}
      selectedValue={this.state.TypeInput}
      onValueChange={
        (itemValue, itemIndex) => {
          this.setState({TypeInput: itemValue, isLoading:true})
          this.componentDidMount()
          this.forceUpdate()
        }
      }>

                            <Picker.Item label="Vegetarian" value="Vegetarian" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Fast Food" value="Fast Food" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Healthy" value="Healthy" />
                            <Picker.Item label="No-Cook" value="No-Cook" />
                            <Picker.Item label="Make Ahead" value="Make Ahead" />

      </Picker>

         <ListView

              dataSource={this.state.dataSource}

              renderSeparator= {this.ListViewItemSeparator}

              renderRow={(rowData) => <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer}
              onPress={this.OpenSecondActivity.bind(this, rowData.RecipeID)}> {rowData.RecipeName} </Text>}

            />



  </View>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seem like the better way to deal with this issue is playing around with **componentDidUpdate()** instead of **componentDidMount()**

Can try refer to my completed application here below.

**Github:** https://github.com/slnn3r/RecipeRedux.git

**The Project above:**

- is using Redux Architecture
- using PHP mySQL database
- using Stack Navigation

Answer (score 1):

You are manually calling `componentDidMount()` which I think is wrong practice. 
According to docs

> `componentDidMount()` is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request.

In your case what I would suggest is when you are changing the value in picker, have some different handler function which will take care of updating the state. You should not manually call `componentDidMount()`, as it is one of the lifecycle hooks of the component.

More on [Component Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

Above code now seems to be fine, in your code, once you receive the updated data, you can update the datasource of the ListView as below,

```
...
fetch('https://unsurfaced-cross.000webhostapp.com/createRN.php', {
...
.then((responseJson) => {
   this.setState({dataSource: responseJson})
}
...
```

And you `ListView`, should be something like this

```
<ListView
  automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
  dataSource={ds.cloneWithRows(this.state.dataSource)}
  renderRow={(rowData)=> {
    return <View>
          <Text style={rowStyle.label} content={rowData.someField} />
        </View>
  }}
  ...
/>
```

Comment: I have tried to create another function with the same code like the componentDidMount() to be called, but same issue occurred, I wonder if it is the problem of the fetch() function.

Comment: can you post the proper code with your ListView also. Happy to help

Comment: where is render method ? Please update question with proper code for better understanding

Comment: Above code seems to be fine. Where are you rendering  your ListView and how are trying to update the datasource. Please post that